# Displaying names in my database instead of RFID card numbers

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to setup an RFID system where my database will display the name of the person tagging their card. I have 2 databases that are linked using the tag no. of the card. The 'tag_logs' database simply displays the cards being tagged. The 'Peoples' database contains user information linked to the card. The databases are setup on phpMyadmin.

['Peoples' Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5FYB.png)

[Tag_Logs Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHYzq.png)

I would like to display the name of the user assigned to the card within the 'tag_no' field, instead of the card number. I attempted to join both databases using a SQL query, with little luck. Can anyone point me to some useful references that will guide me to putting together my SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need a table in which tag numbers are coupled with the owner name. Then you can query this table to show the owner name based on the tag number

You should then launch a query like:

```
SELECT name
FROM People p
WHERE p.tag = 3; -- feel free to change 3 with any value
```

This query will match all the tags in People which are equal to 3, we suppose that tag is a unique key so just one match, and show the relative name.

Comment: The tag number is already coupled with an owner name, within the Peoples table. I'm currently facing some difficulty with displaying these names.

Comment: Then you just need to a SQL query on the people table. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I'm still quite new to SQL. I was looking for a reference link or a guide that might help me put the query together.

Comment: W.r.t a guide, i suggest you this if you are really new. [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I somewhat have a better idea of what to do but it's still somewhat vague. Would it be possible for you to guide me through this please? So within the Peoples table, do I need to include an insert statement that puts the name data into the tag logs table?

Comment: To just find the name of the owner based on it's tag number you don't need any tag log table. If you want to make a log you can for sure use something like 'INSERT yourTag INTO tagLogs'

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far. I'm maintaining a tag logs table to record users who tag their cards. I just inserted the SQL statement mentioned above and I've had no luck. I only require the system to catch the name from the table and display it on the tag log once the card is scanned.

Comment: So it's not a tag log but it's a name log! Then you should just change 'yourTag' with the query in the answer. This way you can insert the name of the guy who used the card into the tagLog table. But in this case you should rename that table to something more appropriate like userLog.
I suggest you to log tags(numbers) instead of names(string) as they can be better used in other queries i.e. join query

Comment: Alright thank you for that, i'll see what I can do!